# Javascript custom eventlistener not working?

Tags: javascript

These are the sections of code from my custom event listeners that is not working.

Why does this return '-1' `var idx=functionList[eventType].indexOf(callback)` when they are the same?

When I use the following in the `myObject.removeCustomEventListenr()` method

```
console.log(functionList[eventType][0]) /*the console shows 
function(){console.log('firedEvent')*/
console.log(callback) /*the console shows 
function(){console.log('firedEvent')*/
```

both the same thing so why does it not work

Below is the full part that is causing trouble

```
var myObject = {}
var functionList = {}

myObject.addCustomEventListener = function(eventType,callback){
    if(!functionList[eventType]){
        functionList[eventType] = []
    }
    functionList[eventType].push(callback)
    //creates functionList.start[0] = function(){console.log('firedEvent')}
}

myObject.removeCustomEventListener = function(eventType,callback){
    if(functionList[eventType]){
        var idx = functionList[eventType].indexOf(callback)
        console.log(idx) //logs '-1' should however match and return 0
        if(idx!=-1){
            functionList[eventType].splice(idx,1)
            console.log('removed')//obviously does not remove the function form the array
        }
    }
}

myObject.addCustomEventListener('start',function(){console.log('firedEvent')})
myObject.removeCustomEventListener('start',function(){console.log('firedEvent')})
```

Please explain why this occurs and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing references to 2 different functions to the `add` and `remove` functions, here:

```
myObject.addCustomEventListener('start',function(){console.log('firedEvent')})
myObject.removeCustomEventListener('start',function(){console.log('firedEvent')})
```

While the code in the functions is the same, they're both separate objects as far as JavaScript is concerned, meaning you can't find one when passing the other to `indexOf()`

This should work:

```
var callback = function(){
    console.log('firedEvent')
};
myObject.addCustomEventListener('start', callback)
myObject.removeCustomEventListener('start', callback)
```

```js
var myObject = {}
var functionList = {}

myObject.addCustomEventListener = function(eventType,callback){
    if(!functionList[eventType]){
        functionList[eventType] = []
    }
    functionList[eventType].push(callback)
    //creates functionList.start[0] = function(){console.log('firedEvent')}
}

myObject.removeCustomEventListener = function(eventType,callback){
    if(functionList[eventType]){
        var idx = functionList[eventType].indexOf(callback)
        console.log(idx) //logs '-1' should however match and return 0
        if(idx!=-1){
            functionList[eventType].splice(idx,1)
            alert('removed')//obviously does not remove the function form the array
        }
    }
}
var callback = function(){
    console.log('firedEvent')
};
myObject.addCustomEventListener('start', callback);
myObject.removeCustomEventListener('start', callback);
```

Comment: Yep, two objects (function is object too) are never equal even though they have exactly the same content.

Comment: Ok thanks.Would it be fine to add the following underneath 
`if(idx==-1){
  var demoList=functionList[eventType]
  for(x in demoList){
   if(demoList[x].toString()==callback.toString()){idx=x;break}
  }
}`

Comment: @Kwiksilver: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve with that piece of code...

Comment: Turn all the 'functions' in the array into a string and them compare them with the `callback.toString()`. Basically compare the functions as strings then if they are equal it will set `idx` equal to the point int the array that matches. I meant to say add underneath `var idx = functionList[eventType].indexOf(callback)`.

Comment: @Kwiksilver: `if(demoList[x] == callback)` should work